# How do I get rid of this Valgrind warning and use argv[]?

Tags: c, file, valgrind, argv

I am quite new to C programming and I am coding this program to read in a file and prints out into a table the automatically aligns itself. Everything works perfectly but I am getting a Valgrind warning that states, conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s). I also need to be able to pass in any .txt file not just a specific .txt file. I know that I can use argv but not sure how to use it in a function than call it in main.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// constant to store the maximum size of the records that can be read from the file

enum
{
    // update MAX_SIZE to if the number of rows is more than 1000
    MAX_SIZE = 1024
};

// structure to store a record from the file
typedef struct
{
    char define[20];
    char octal[26];
    char description[1000];
} Record;

// string to store the header of the table
char header1[20], header2[20], header3[20];

// function to read the file and return the maximum length of the descriptions read from the file
void readFile(Record rec[], int *size,int *length, int *length1, int *length2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int maxLength,maxLength1,maxLength2=0;
    // open a file for input
    FILE *fp = fopen("input2.txt", "r");

    // check if the file opened successfully
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not be opened!");
        exit(1);
    }

    
    // read the file
    // first we read the header of each column from the file
    fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s\n", header1, header2, header3);

    // now we read each record from the file
    while (fscanf(fp, "%20s ", rec[i].define) == 1)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%20s '%[^']'", rec[i].octal, rec[i].description);

        // find the length of the description and update the 'maxLength'
        if(strlen(rec[i].description) > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = strlen(rec[i].description);
        }
        else if(strlen(rec[i].octal) > maxLength1)
        {
            maxLength1 = strlen(rec[i].octal);  
        }
        else if(strlen(rec[i].define) > maxLength2)
        {
            maxLength2 = strlen(rec[i].define);
        }
        
        // increment the value of i
        i++;
    }

    printf(" Length: %d \n", maxLength);    

    // close the input file
    fclose(fp);

    // update the number of records read from the file
    *size = i;    
    *length = maxLength;
    *length1 = maxLength1;
    *length2 = maxLength2;
}

void printTable(Record rec[], int size, int length, int length1, int length2)
{
    if(length2 >= 15)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+17; i++)
            printf("-");

        printf("\n| %-*s | %*s | %-*s |\n", length2,header1, length1, header2,  length, header3);

        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+17; i++)
            printf("-");
        printf("\n");

        // print the table data
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("| %-*s | %10s | %-*s |\n",length2, rec[i].define,  rec[i].octal, length, rec[i].description);

        // print the footer
        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+17; i++)
            printf("-");
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("length: %d \n", length2);
        // print the header of the table
        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+10; i++)
            printf("-");

        printf("\n| %-*s | %*s | %-*s |\n", length2,header1, length1, header2,  length, header3);

        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+10; i++)
            printf("-");
        printf("\n");

        // print the table data
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("| %-*s | %*s | %-*s |\n",length2, rec[i].define, length1, rec[i].octal, length, rec[i].description);

        // print the footer
        for (int i = 0; i < length+length1+length2+10; i++)
            printf("-");
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// driver function
int main()
{
    // create an array of recors of MAX_SIZE
    Record recs[MAX_SIZE];
    // initialize size of recs to zero
    int size = 0;
    int length=0;
    int length1=0;
    int length2=0;

    // call readFile() function to read data from the file and update the size of recs
    readFile(recs, &size,&length,&length1,&length2);
     
    // call printTable() function to print the table in a well-formatted manner
    printTable(recs, size, length,length1,length2);

    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind warning:

```
==1821== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1821== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1821== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1821== Command: ./main input2.txt
==1821== 
==1821== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1821==    at 0x10896F: readFile (main.c:50)
==1821==    by 0x108E17: main (main.c:147)
==1821== 
==1821== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1821==    at 0x1089C2: readFile (main.c:54)
==1821==    by 0x108E17: main (main.c:147)
```

Comment: Another possible oversight in your code is that `maxLength` is defined as `int` but compared to `size_t`. It's probably best to use `size_t` for the maxLength variables too.

Comment: In addition to the `maxLength` and `maxLength1` not being initialized and being the wrong type to take a `strlen()` return value of `size_t` as @Cheatah mentioned, you may still see this error from valgrind because the entirety of the `rec[i].description` field isn't initialized on read before being walked thru by `strlen()`; if this is the case, you will need to change `Record recs[MAX_SIZE];` in `main()` to `Record recs[MAX_SIZE] = {0};` to initialize all of the record structure memory.

Answer (score 2):

`int maxLength,maxLength1,maxLength2=0;` does not initialize `maxLength` or `maxLength1`.

Answer (score 2):

It's trying to tell you that `maxLength` and `maxLength1` are uninitialized variables.

You have this line for declaration:

```
int maxLength,maxLength1,maxLength2=0;
```

But only `maxLength2` is initialized to zero in that statement. The other two variables have undefined values.

Hence, when the code gets to line 50 or line 54 and makes this comparison:

```
    if(strlen(rec[i].description) > maxLength){
```

It's uncertain what `maxLength` was expected to be.

Comment: Suggestion: Perhaps OP meant to write something like: `int maxLength,maxLength1,maxLength2; maxLength = maxLength1 = maxLength2 = 0;`? Although personally, I think it's best to put every declaration/initialization on a separate line.

Comment: Another option: `int maxLength = 0, maxLength1 = 0, maxLength2 = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use declarations like this:

```
int maxLength,maxLength1,maxLength2=0;
```

it's dangerous and difficult to read because `maxLength` and `maxLength1` will not be initialized to 0.

Instead declare each variable on a separate line, which is far more readable:

```
int maxLength = 0;
int maxLength1 = 0;
int maxLength2 = 0;
```